# Split-Zone DNS Windows Server 2016 not responding to external dns queries

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2016, windows-dns, split-dns

I am attempting to setup a split-brain dns in my active directory domain. In a nutshell, two of my servers have both external and internal IP's. When a DNS query is performed for them, both the internal and external IP's are returned. I would like to only have the external IP returned when the client computer is on the external network. I believe I can do that via this [tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/dns/deploy/dns-sb-with-ad). Once I apply the DnsServerQueryResolutionPolicy to my external scope, I am not able to resolve any DNS names for my domains when querying the external adapter. I have verified that the dns zone scopes are populated with the proper records.

Any and all help is appreciated or if there is a better strategy to accomplish this, that is great too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I incorrectly configured the record causing the error. Instead of adding just the machine name to the record, I added the FQDN which in turn appended the rest of the domain name to the record. By only adding the machine name, it worked as desired.